# Expresión regular para validar una placa de automóvil

Tags: java, regex

Necesito implementar en java la validación de placas de vehículos que cumplan con alguna de las siguientes formas

- AAA-000-A
- AAA-00-AA
  En donde `A` es cualquier letra mayúscula de la A a la Z y `0` es cualquier dígito.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
String placa;

  placa="AAA-000-A"; //Caso 1
//placa="AAA-00-00"; //Caso 2

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{3}[-][0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{1}) | ([A-Z]{3}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2})");
Matcher mt = p.matcher(placa);
            
if(mt.find() == true){
  System.out.println("Las placas son validas");
}else{
  System.out.println("Las placas no son validas");
}
```

Cuando pruebo los dos casos de placas ninguno me funciona. ¿Cuál es la falla?

Answer (score 1):

Debe corregir la expresión regular que está utilizando en el instanciamiento de `Pattern` por la siguiente:

```
Pattern p = "^([A-Z]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[A-Z]{1})|([A-Z]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})\z";
```

El error que tiene en su expresión regular es que alrededor del simbolo `|` tiene unos caracteres espacios que hacen que su expresion regular exija espacio a derecha para el primer patrón (el de un digito al final) y espacio a izquierda para el segundo patron (2 digitos al final)

La expresión regular que propongo contiene tambien el símbolo `^` al principio y `\z` al final que indican que la cadena tiene que estar compuesta solo por una cadena que en su totalidad se ajuste al patrón. De no colocarse estos delimitadores, cualquier cadena que tenga una subcadena que cumpla con el patrón haría match.